# Why is trace bitmap not working in inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, shapes

I had created a rectangle and was trying to use the trace bitmap feature to make a SVG copy but the copy was not being created.

[image: This is what i did]

Comment: Did you make the rectangle in Inkscape?

Comment: Yes, i did make it in inkscape

Answer (score 2):

Your rectangle already is in vector format, all you need to do is save it as an SVG.

The reason the tracing failed, is that you aren't tracing a bitmap image, rather you were attempting to trace a vector shape.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the stupid question, i am a mere beginner